# Space which is $T_1$ and sober but not Hausdorff?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Every Hausdorff space is $T_1$ and sober. Does the converse hold? I expect not. What's a counterexample?

I expected I should be able to look this up in *Counterexamples in Topology*, but unfortunately that book doesn't appear to discuss sober spaces.

Comment: [Wikipedia has an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space). "Let X be the set of real numbers, with a new point p adjoined; the open sets being all real open sets, and all cofinite sets containing p."

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I suppose more generally one can take any infinite $T_1$ and sober space $Y$ and adjoin a new point in a similar manner to get a $T_1$ and sober space which is not Hausdorff.

Comment: I've just added references to this example to a few relevant nlab pages.

Comment: I recommend making Nate's comment a CW answer, accepting it, and then this question is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nate Eldredge points out in the comments, there's a counterexample on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space). See there or Nate's comment for a description.